# How do I add a JNDI entry called "properties" in Glassfish on startup without using the admin?

Tags: glassfish, jndi

In the code for our project there is this line:

```
(Properties) new InitialContext().lookup("properties")
```

One of the other developers said I had to add the entry through the admin for my instance of Glassfish. Having to use the admin to do this seemed suspect to me. Isn't there a way to add a JNDI entry at startup in web.xml, or something similar?

Comment: I suggest that you check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497468/inject-a-file-using-resource-and-jndi-in-jee6/18550778#18550778

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea here is that it *must* be done via the admin application so that the values aren't embedded in the application.

Comment: This is just a custom JNDI resource entry. These are typically contained in context and web configuration files anyhow.

Comment: @hal10001 So put it there. I think you should be talking with your other developer.

Comment: I need to know what the resource reference looks like. In Glassfish this is a custom resource, which when configured looks to create a java.util.Property. Before asking him about it I want to know if it is even possible.