# Inject a file using @Resource and JNDI in JEE6

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-6, jndi

Is it possible to inject a file using JNDI and @Resource in JEE6?

If so how do I setup and JNDI (file) resource in Glassfish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objective is to configure a properties file as follows:

```
@Inject
@Resource("META-INF/aws.properties")
Properties awsProperties;
```

then you want to use a WELD extension which is explained in the WELD documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/extensions/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#gettingstarted)

It is as simple as adding this to your POM

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
      <artifactId>weld-extensions</artifactId>
      <version>${weld.extensions.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

#### Otherwise

See this [article](http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/06/inject-java-properties-in-java-ee-using-cdi/) for a programmatic approach.

#### Or else,

Store your properties in a DB schema table and use JPA 2.0 to retrieve them using JTA pointing to your JNDI.

#### Or if your application is a JSF one:

1. Add a resource bundle in the faces-config.xml file as follows:

   ```
    <application>
       <resource-bundle>
           <base-name>/YourProperties</base-name>
           <var>yourProperties</var>
       </resource-bundle>
   </application>
   ```
2. Add the corresponding YourProperties.properties file in your classpath or maven resources folder as follows:
   [image: Maven resource folder]
3. In your container managed bean add the following snippet:

   ```
   private String someString;

   @PostConstruct
   public void loadProperty(){
       someString = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/YourProperties").getString("prop1");
    }
   ```

Comment: Do you know of any similar extension in Apache's CDI implementation OpenWebbeans?

Comment: I am sorry I don't. I am curious to ask how did you replace WELD by Open WebBeabs in Glassfish?

Comment: I didn't but our deployment needs to be able to move between JEE containers without any/much change.

Comment: Then use the programmatic approach because JEE6 does not have a specification for injecting properties files